# SQL Server Query - How to append row showing total record count?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best approach to append a row to a SQL Server query showing the total count of rows resulting from the query?  `UNION` is one way, but seems very inefficient:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT STR(COUNT(col1)), NULL FROM tbl1
```

`ROLLUP` isn't an option because it requires `GROUP BY`, which we're not using for the queries in question.

Comment: The best approach arguably is "not". It's trivial for the client side to do something with the number of rows, and this seems like a classic problem of client-side presentation. Server-side, all your options are bad: selecting into a temp table or table variable just so you can append the row count and then return it is very inefficient, as is any aggregate you could fold into the query itself. If your client can handle multiple rowsets, you can `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT`, but handling multiple rowsets correctly is a rare ability. (And no, putting that into a `UNION` directly will not work.)

Comment: Does it have to be a row? Could not add `count(*) over () as record_count` as another column?

Comment: I've tried this before and usually the temp-table solution is the next best choice *if* returning @@rowcount as a second result set is not an option, or as a stored procedure return value.

Comment: @PhilCoulson, thanks but it does need to be a row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GROUPING SETS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#group-by-grouping-sets--) for this

```sql
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(col1) = 0 THEN col1 ELSE CAST(COUNT(*) AS varchar(30)) END AS col1,
  col2
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (col1, col2),
    ()
);
```

The `GROUPING` function will tell you whether the row is the Total row or not.

This does have the effect of grouping the columns which could be a different result and possibly less efficient. But if you include a unique/primary key as the first column in the grouping list then this shouldn't make a difference, and should be almost as performant as the original query.

---

You can also use a window function, which will return the total on each row as another column

```sql
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  COUNT(*) OVER ()
FROM tbl1;
```

Comment: This is a semantics-altering transformation, because `GROUP BY` will implicitly remove duplicates. (And, of course, there may be a performance impact, potentially prohibitive.)

Comment: Even if you include the primary key, `GROUP BY` will not be "clever enough" to elide the sort. The `COUNT(*) OVER ()` aggregate approach, while short to type and not changing the semantics (well -- if we ignore the new column of course), is potentially even worse in terms of performance, since all rows must be counted before the first one is even streamed to the client. This can cause some fierce spooling.

Comment: @JeroenMostert No sort in this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=796afc2f0123c0cd905d7bc7dd050dc5 and as far as I am aware, the compiler can recognize a "pointless" grouping in most cases. I agree on the window function, however it may be the only option if there is no unique column

Comment: Ah, I see -- it *can* elide the sort, but you must take care to put the clustered index up front, otherwise it still fails to see that the combination is unique (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83412136328f5058d7aa9fa7838fcb37), or rather, it won't see it can just read off the index in order. Important gotcha! (And note that even with the sort elided, the "stream aggregate" is of course still there, but I don't know if that's measurable on a large dataset or if you effectively only end up paying for the totals row.)

Comment: @Charlieface, the GROUPING SETS seems to work well.  There does happen to be a primary key included in every query where this is needed, so no issue there for us.  I don't know if this is better than UNION performance-wise, but we'll test it out.  Thanks!

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good spot. The `Stream Aggregate` will always be there, as that is what is aggregating the rows to create the rollup (you will see rollup info in the XML). On a large dataset I would expect it to affect performance a small amount, but it's likely faster than any other possible solution in pure T-SQL, especially if complex joins and filters are involved in creating the original dataset.